# Редактирование web.xml в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, web.xml

Есть ли в IntelliJ IDEA инструмент, помогающий редактировать web.xml не вручную (как в NetBeans)?

В [документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/specifying-the-servlet-name-and-the-target-package.html#defineServletName) к IDEA 15 сказано: "open web.xml and switch to the General tab. Then click + in the Servlets Configured pane". Никак не могу найти этот "**Servlets Configured pane**".

[Другой пример](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/specifying-the-servlet-initialization-parameters.html) из документации говорит о "**Servlet Initialization Params pane**" и отсылает нас по мертвой ссылке(

У меня при открытии web.xml не появляется каких-то дополнительных панелей, окон, вкладок. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: У Вас IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition? Насколько я помню только Ultimate имеет плагины для работы с web.xml.

Comment: У меня Ultimate. Попробую поискать в сторону плагинов. Странно, что в документации такое написано, а на самом деле ничего нет по дефолту.